# In the given circuit would CY2 connect the grounds leading to non isolated circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis, emc, isolation, isolated

[image]

Here's the datasheet for the part being used
https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pdqe10-d.pdf
I'm using this part to isolate different parts of a circuit.
The schematic above is the recommended EMC circuit.
Would CY2 non cancel out the isolation parts of the circuit because it would be connecting the grounds?

Comment: No, it will not cancel DC isolation. It will present impedance to AC frequencies. What is it that you need isolated, and is any side considered "live" i.e. mains-referenced, or earthed, or floating?

Comment: The CYs allow common mode switching noise pumped to the output to flow back to the primary side where it originated. These are small caps that help with EMC and should be rated for high isolated voltage if necessary. At low f, these caps are almost irrelevant

Comment: @Justme I'm building a guitar pedal power supply with 5 outputs that have to be isolated from one another